# How do I create a squeeze tube packaging?

Tags: modeling, path

I've just moved from Cinema4D to Blender and I would like to create a squeeze tube where it is rounded at the bottom and tapers into a thin ellipse at the top. In Cinema4D I used a loft nurb and a circle spline. I've found the cirlce path in Blender but how do I connect them to create this shape?

Thank you for any help.

Edit: I want to create packaging like the image below.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you hope to accomplish?

Comment: I've added an image in to the original post of what I'm looking to create.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe a mesh approach instead of a curve approach will be faster. This is my final result:

[image]

### The Procedure

Delete the default cube by keying <kbd>X</kbd> to open the *Delete* menu and keying <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Mesh > Cylinder* adds a cylinder. <kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>Z</kbd>, then <kbd>3</kbd> scales the cylinder up on on the *Z-Axis* by a factor of *3*.

[image]

<kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode*. Place the cursor in the middle of the tube but to the right side, a few pixels to the right of the red arrowhead shown in the above image. To add loopcuts so our mesh has both more detail and square faces, key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, then <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>8</kbd>. Do not do anything else. Your mesh should look like the following. Note the pink loops around the circumference.

[image]

Key <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> immediately to confirm the loopcuts in their default position. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> while hovering the cursor over the topmost edgeloop to select it. Key <kbd>O</kbd> to turn on *Proportional Editing* and set the *Proportional Editing Falloff Type* to *Sharp* ([image] in the *3D Viewport Menu Bar*). *Proportional Editing* will allow us to move multiple edge loops at once in proportion to one another. Key <kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, then <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>, then <kbd>[image: MW] MW</kbd> scroll up until you have a white circle about the size shown in the following image (*6.12*). This will stretch the top of the squeeze tube outward giving it its distinctive curvy edges.

[image]

Confirm the scaling with <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Key <kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd>, then <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>, then <kbd>[image: MW] MW</kbd> scroll up until you have a white circle about size *9.85*. Confirm the scaling with <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will thin the top into part two of its distinctive shape, shown below.

[image]

Key <kbd>E</kbd>, then <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to extrude the top of the squeeze tube up along the top face's *Normal*. This gives the tube its heat sealed top thing. Key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then <kbd>2</kbd> to switch to *Edge Select Mode*. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> to select these edge loops:

[image]

Key <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, then <kbd>1</kbd>. This *Creases* the edges so that they stay in their modeled position during a *Subsurf* operation, performed next. <kbd>Tab</kbd> out of *Edit Mode*. Go to the *Properties panel > Object Modifiers tab* and add a *Subdivision surface* and *Edge split* modifier, shown below. The *Subsurf* will smooth the mesh, while the *Edge Split* will retain hard edges at the *Creased* edges after *Smooth* shading the mesh, performed next.

[image]

Go to the *3D Viewport > Toolshelf > Tools tab > Edit dropdown* and select *Smooth* shading.

Here is the .blend file:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I will try it out. I really appreciate all of your time and help.

Comment: The top part is reason I've gone with the plane. It creates ugly ngon and it isn't straight. Filling it with grid fill or merge at center isn't a good way too.

Comment: @Shiro Glad that it helped you!

Comment: Can you add in your answers a bit more short explanations of your steps instead of strict listing used keyboard shortcuts ? It's a bit hard to read that because one has to have very good imagination to visualize your procedure.

Comment: @MrZak Ok, I'm listening. Can you comment an example of what I wrote and then how you might improve upon it? I'm not quite sure I understand exactly what's troubling about it. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I've already wrote what looks weird. Your procedure consists of wall of shortcuts and commands assumed to do. You provide info about *how* to do (imho *too much* detailed, but whatever) but rarely about *why* and *what* in fact are you doing (short resume). Have you ever tried to visualize to yourself those isntructions without opening Blender ? One has to switch back and forth between Blender and browser in order to make your step-by-step. It's hard to remember "S > Z > 0, RMB, E, A" etc. It's much easier when it's "Scale faces to 0 by Z axis to flatten them, select one, extrude, deselect".

Comment: @MrZak Ok, I'll look at it. Maybe the reason I generally don't do it is because I *can* visualize what all the shortcuts do without Blender. Also, most OPs can, too, because so far, I haven't heard back from any of them :) Another reason that I write in keyboard shortcuts is so anyone with even a minuscule amount of knowledge pertaining to Blender can understand and make what I make. People like us might not need it, but some noob who stumbles across this post still might.

Comment: @MrZak See my edits. If you approve, please consider upvoting :). If you still don't, I'll welcome more input.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Final]

In this case I would not go with Curves as they aren't best choice in terms of modeling in Blender. My method is based upon simple plane which gives us very simple base geometry and allows to have nice top part of model. Starting with circle will give massive headache to close and straighten up this part of a mesh.

This is method I've used to model it:

1. Add a *Plane* - <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Mesh* > *Plane*.
2. Go to *Edit Mode*.
3. Select all vertices, press <kbd>E</kbd> and extrude along Z axis.
4. Select top edge and press <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>Y</kbd> to squize it.
5. Extrude top edge along Z axis once more.

You should have now something like this:

[image: First]

6. Add Modifier > *Subdivision surface* and set it to 4-5 (preview and render).

Now we need to crease some edges.

7. Select all top vertices and set *Mean Crease* to about 0.6.

[image: Second]

8. Do the same with bottom vertices but this time *Mean Crease* should be 0.3.
9. Add *Loop Cut* (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> then hover cursor over mesh) to 'main part' of the mesh and place it near bottom edge.
10. Choose *Smooth Shading*. *Object Mode* > *Tools Panel* (left side of the screen) > *Shading* > *Smooth*.

[image: Third]

**Here is blend file to play with:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with this in so much detail, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I've forget to add step to set Smooth Shading. You could set it in Object Mode > Tools Panel (left side of the screen) > Shading > Smooth. I'll add it to the edit.

Answer (score 5):

Blender does support NURBS but its support is quite limited at the moment.  What you are looking for is Add -> Surface -> Nurbs Cylinder.  Then you would have to manually tweak the control points to generate the desired shape.

[image]

Comment: That's great, thank you. How did you add more control points to it?

Comment: Just selected one loop and extruded (E key).